# HTML column widths set via thead not honored if thead hidden

Tags: html, css

So for a while I've used thead td elements to set the column widths in html tables.  But now I'm testing this in IE 11 and it doesn't seem to be working.  It doesn't work in chrome or edge either.
In this example I hide the thead as it isn't needed via display:none.  But then the column widths aren't recognized. The option buttons should be 2em width and the labels 23em width and then the last column is set to auto.  I've included a copepen for it as well.  Let me know the best way to accomplish setting table column widths via css.

```
<form id="frmRequest" name="frmRequest" method="post" action="pgRequest.aspx">
   <div id="content">
      <div id="contentMain">
         <div class="request_form">
         <div id="request_type">
            <table class="request_type">
                  <caption>Reason For Conflicts Check</caption>
                  <thead>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="col1">Column 1</td>
                        <td class="col2">Column 2</td>
                        <td class="col3">Column 3</td>
                     </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="data col1"><input value="3" name="optIntakeType" type="radio" id="optIntakeTypeNewClientMatter" checked="checked" /></td>
                        <td class="label col2" colspan="2"><label for="optIntakeTypeNewClientMatter">Taking on a New Client &amp; Opening a Matter</label></td>                        
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="data col1"><input value="4" name="optIntakeType" type="radio" id="optIntakeTypeNewMatter" /></td>
                        <td class="label col2" colspan="2"><label for="optIntakeTypeNewMatter">Taking on a New Matter of an Existing Client</label></td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="data col1"><input value="1" name="optIntakeType" type="radio" id="optIntakeTypeExistingClient" /></td>
                        <td class="label col2"><label for="optIntakeTypeExistingClient">Add Related Parties to an Existing Client</label></td>
                        <td class="lookup col3">
                           <div id="existing_client">
                           <label for="txtExistingClient">Client</label>
                           <input name="txtExistingClient" type="text" id="txtExistingClient" size="15" maxlength="14" class="text uppercase" />
                           <button id="cmdExistingClientLookup" name="cmdExistingClientLookup" type="button" value="LOOKUP"><img src="../images/search16.gif" alt="SEARCH"></button>
                           <span id="lblExistingClient"></span>
                           </div>
                        </td> 
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="data col1"><input value="0" name="optIntakeType" type="radio" id="optIntakeTypeExistingMatter" /></td>
                        <td class="label col2"><label for="optIntakeTypeExistingMatter">Add Related Parties to an Existing Matter</label></td>
                        <td class="lookup col3">
                           <div id="existing_matter">
                           <label for="txtExistingMatter">Matter</label>
                           <input name="txtExistingMatter" type="text" id="txtExistingMatter" size="15" maxlength="15" class="text uppercase" />
                           <button id="cmdExistingMatterLookup" name="cmdExistingMatterLookup" type="button" value="LOOKUP"><img src="../images/search16.gif" alt="SEARCH"></button>
                           <span id="lblExistingMatter"></span>
                           </div>
                        </td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td class="data col1"><input value="5" name="optIntakeType" type="radio" id="optIntakeTypeFreeSearch" /></td>
                        <td class="label col2" colspan="2"><label for="optIntakeTypeFreeSearch">Conflict Check For Research Only</label></td>
                     </tr>
                  </tbody>
               </table>
           </div>
           </div>
     </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

```
input.uppercase
   {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   }

input.error
   {
    border: 1px solid #FF0000;
   }

.error
   {
   color: #FF0000;
   }

div.request_form
   {
   text-align: left;
   width: 97%;
   border: 2px outset #CCAACC;
   padding: 1em 1em 1em 1em;
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 10pt;
   }

table caption
   {
   color: #000000;
   font-size: 11pt;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: left;
   padding-bottom: 0.5em;
   }

#request_type
   {
   margin: 0.5em 0em 0em 0em;
   padding: 0;
   width: 100%;
   border: 0px solid #00FF00;
   }

table.request_type
   {
   margin: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
   width: 100%;
   border-spacing: 0px;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   table-layout: fixed;
   clear: none;
   }

table.request_type, table.request_type tr, table.request_type td
   {
   border: 1px inset #AAAAAA;
   }

table.request_type
   {
   border: 0px inset #AAAAAA;
   }

table.request_type tr
   {
   height: 1.5em;
   }

table.request_type td
   {
   font-weight: normal;
   font-size: 10pt;
   padding: 0em 0em 0em 0em;
   }

table.request_type tbody td.label
   {
   font-size: 11pt;
   font-weight: normal;
   color: #0000CC;
   width: 10em;
   padding-left: 0em;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   }

table.request_type tbody td.data
   {
   color: #000000;
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: top;
   font-family: courier, monospace;
   font-size: 10pt;
   font-weight: normal;
   }

table.request_type tbody td.lookup
   {
   text-align: left;
   }

table.request_type tbody td.lookup input
   {
   vertical-align: middle;
   }

table.request_type tbody td.lookup button
   {
   vertical-align: middle;
   width: 32px;
   }

table.request_type thead
   {
   display: none;
   }

table.request_type td.col1
   {
   width: 2em;
   }

table.request_type td.col2
   {
   width: 23em;
   }

table.request_type td.col3
   {
   width: auto;
   }

#existing_client
   {
   border: 0px solid #FF0000;
   visibility: hidden;
   }

#existing_matter
   {
   border: 0px solid #FF0000;
   visibility: hidden;
   }
```

https://codepen.io/Will_Rickards/pen/dyYpqKb

Comment: Table header cells should be `<th>`, not `<td>` btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`table-layout: fixed;` means the table's layout is set by the first displayed row. Either use `table-layout: auto` or set the `thead { visibility: collapsed; }`. Not all browsers support `collapsed` right now though.

Also, tip: you don't need classes like `.col1`, `.col2` - use the `nth-child` selector instead:

```
table.request_type {
    /* etc */
    table-layout: auto;
}

table.request_type > thead > tr > th:nth-child(1),
table.request_type > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) {
    width: 2em;
}

table.request_type > thead > tr > th:nth-child(2),
table.request_type > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) {
    width: 23em;
}

table.request_type > thead > tr > th:nth-child(3),
table.request_type > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(3) {
    /* `width: auto;` is implicit, you don't need to set it explicitly. */
}
```

Comment: So normally I wouldn't have col1, col2, col3 in the body of the table.  So when I took them out but just changed table-layout to auto, it did not work.  But changing that and using the nth-child selector did work.  So thanks for that.  I wrote this before CSS3 was a thing.

Comment: "I wrote this before CSS3 was a thing" - okay, you get a free-pass, but just this one time!

Comment: What do you do if the first row has td's with colspan?  I've had to use an essentially empty row there to get it to work but that adds a bit of vertical space.